# Select multiple non contiguous ranges using Range() and Cells()

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to select multiple non contiguous ranges using `RANGE()` and `CELLS()`.

**My worksheet** (Sheet5) **looks something like this:**

```
 | A | B | C |    D   | E |     F     |
 +---+---+---+--------+---+-----------+
1|...|...|...|Category|...|Description|
2|...|...|...|Apple   |...|Fruit      |
3|...|...|...|Carrot  |...|Vegetable  |
4|...|...|...|Hat     |...|Clothing   |
```

- I want to set the `Category` column and the `Description` column to a range that I can copy and paste to another file.
- Column titles are in the first row.
- The columns I'm looking for are **currently** in `Column D` and `Column F` but they are likely to move.
- The two columns are non-contiguous ranges, I don't want to select anything in `Column E` for example.

The code I have so far finds the `Category` column, `Description` column, and the `lastrow`. As I am using variables to select the range, I am using `Range()` and `Cells()`.

**My code:**

```
Sub SelectNonContiguousRangeCells()

'Create variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim strCat As String
Dim strDesc As String
Dim rngCat As Range
Dim rngDesc As Range
Dim rngCopy As Range

'Initialize variables
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Sheet5
lastrow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'Find the column headers
strCat = "Category New"
strDesc = "Requirement Description"
Set rngCat = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find(strCat)
Set rngDesc = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find(strDesc)

'Set the copy range
Set rngCopy = Range(Range(Cells(1, rngCat.Column), Cells(lastrow, rngCat.Column)), Range(Cells(1, rngDesc.Column), Cells(lastrow, rngDesc.Column))).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Debug.Print rngCopy.Address

End Sub
```

The range that returns in my `Debug.Print` here is `$D$1:$F$449`, which is a contiguous range, while I'm hoping to see `$D$1:$D$449,$F$1:$F$449`, which is a non-contiguous range.

I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37262609/8305056) and found some useful information, but it doesn't seem to help with non-contiguous ranges.

I've also been looking through the [Range.Cells documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-cells-property-excel) on MSDN with no luck.

How can I use my variables to select the columns containing `Category` and `Description` without anything in between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Union` to accomplish this.

You also need to code for the option of neither of your header values being found. Otherwise you may end up pushing a value of `Nothing` into a range which will error out

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectNonContiguousRangeCells()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")
Dim rngCat As Range, rngDesc As Range, rngCopy As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rngCat = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find("Category New").Resize(lastrow, 1)
Set rngDesc = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find("Requirement Description").Resize(lastrow, 1)

If Not rngCat Is Nothing Then
    If Not rngDesc Is Nothing Then
        Set rngCopy = Union(rngCat, rngDesc)
    End If
End If

Debug.Print rngCopy.Address (False, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't come across Union before, thank you! And I didn't think of using resize to shorten the code even further. I would just like to clarify, I'm setting `Sheet5`  the sheet [codename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481428/8305056), not the "Sheet5" sheet name, so `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")` needs to be `Set ws = Sheet5`. And agreed on the error handling, the example is great!

Comment: Agh, I was just shortening other things so I could test on my end. None of the changes I made were crucial. `Union` is the only thing you were looking for. I took away some string variables too. If they are only being used once, I just wrap them in quotes. I only dim repetitive strings to avoid blocks of variables. Makes following the code easier as well

Comment: Good point. In my working version of the code I have comments around the dim strings to tell me where to change it if the user changes the name of the column, but I agree the code is cleaner how you have it. Thanks very much.